# Bitrix панель z-index

Tags: битрикс

Как переопределить z-index для bx-panel (http://joxi.ru/V2V6wMXc0YzZj2) и всех ее элементов, чтобы она была поверх всей верстки?

Comment: Абсолютно уверен, что это делается на CSS

Comment: не делайте в своей верстке z-ibdex больше 99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял у вас панель админа выводится под вёрсткой. Если повысите z-index, то тогда панель будет поверх вёрстки. Вообще лично я за такое руки обрываю!
У вас ни в коем не должны:
1) Стили битрикса пересекаться с вашими. Т.е. НЕ ТРОГАТЬ CSS из ядра.
А так же styles.css. Для ваших шаблонов существует tempate_styles.css
2) Ваша вёрстка НИ как не должна влиять на вёрстку Битрикса, иначе получится вот это: https://prnt.sc/i75kq7

В вашем случае может помочь обёртка сайта в div.wrap , который будет выводиться после показа админки. В таком случае, сайт всегда будет ниже админской панели. И в случае открытия её, сайт просто будет съезжать чуть ниже.
Вот ещё один пример не соблюдения подобных правил. http://prntscr.com/i75irb

Answer (score 0):

```
#bx-panel #bx-panel-top {
z-index: 110!important;
}
```